# Can we access network file in windows service running under local system?

Tags: c#, file, networking, directory

I have windows service which runs under local system account.
I am checking File.Exist(File in the network). this works fine with windows 7 but when i run this service on windows xp sp3 then it return false for file.exists().
Any help???

Comment: folder shared have full access to 'EveryOne'.

Comment: Does the file have any specific permissions?

Comment: no full access is given to every user no permission is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.. 
LocalSystem intentionally does not have NETWORK rights so that services can be run under that account and be "safe" from attacks that would touch the network.

So you did right - change it to some other account - LocalSystem won't work for a service doing network access.

Comment: LocalSystem DOES have network access, but under local machine account and presents anonymous credentials : https://serverfault.com/questions/135867/how-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account